# which is the proper way to push notifications to another webserver

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, playframework, push-notification

We have an API built on Rails, and processing some stuff with resque. After the process now, I need to send a notification to the client (which is an app built with Play Framework, that sends a json file to the API with the data to be processed with resque).
I found [Faye](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye), [Private Pub](http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub) and a [lot of others](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=rails%20%2b%20push%20notificationj&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#q=rails%20%2b%20send%20push%20notification&hl=pt-BR&safe=off&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&prmd=imvns&ei=ldG7T_vrMZCk8AT6-NHDCg&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=d27cccdf103b0c9c&biw=1368&bih=600) but they only have examples to notify a page (like a chat window and so), and not a webserver.
any ideas? thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean "notify a webserver". Webservers are **servers**, they serve **requests**. If you want to "notify" a webserver of something you request an URL on it `http://mywebserver/notification?msg=hello`. Then you need to have something running on the back end to process this "notification". However I think you need to elaborate a bit more what you exactly are trying to do, as I suspect this is not the answer you were looking for. So you need to explain in more detail what you are doing and what you want.

Comment: with `webserver` I mean my App built with Play. This App builds and sends a json to my RoR API and after the background process, I need to tell this App (the 'play' one) that the process was sucessful or not

Comment: Right, ok. Then I still think the solution is for you background process (the RoR app) to call a predefined URL on your Play app when it is finished. Like `http://the_play_app/background_job_finished?id=123`. I.e. use a callback type notification system.

Comment: That could fit too. Thanks a lot, I will be evaluating all the possibilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've done it with [faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/). Works pretty well